# how to strip ?url= and set as href variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I currently have this jquery but it won't work. if it helps my url is `http://link-ads.blogspot.com/`

the jquery also makes sure the `href` has `http://` if not present in `?url=`

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var url = "document.location.href"
url = url.split('?url=')[1].split(/\?|\%3F/)[0];
if (url.indexOf('http://') == -1)  url = 'http://' + url;
$("a#download").attr("href",url);
  </script>

<a href="" id="download" class="button">continue</a>
```

Comment: Is my understanding correct? - the url of your page is http://link-ads.blogspot.com/?url=foo and you want the <a> tag to become <a href="foo">

Comment: yes and no, if the url is `http://link-ads.blogspot.com/?url=foo"` i want it to autmatically change that to `<a href="http://foo>` unless the adress already has `http:// present http://link-ads.blogspot.com/?url=http://foo`

Comment: Could you edit your question to include example inputs and outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice two issues

```
var url = "document.location.href"
```

should be changed to

```
var url = document.location.href
```

also before you do this line

```
url = url.split('?url=')[1].split(/\?|\%3F/)[0];
```

you should make sure that this is possible with something like

```
if (url.indexOf("?url=") != -1 )
```

otherwise you will get an exception because there won't be a [1] element in the array

Comment: Or `if( /\?url=/i.test( url ) )` instead.

Comment: doesn't work i currently have  `<script type='text/javascript'>
var url = document.URL
if( /\?url=/i.test( url ) )
url = url.split('?url=')[1].split(/\?|\%3F/)[0];
if (url.indexOf('http://') == -1)  url = 'http://' + url;
$("a#download").attr("href",url);
  </script>`